# Location Updates in Android 11

Tags: android, service, location, android-11

My app traces location updates in foreground services periodically started from background and is working properly in Android Q after adding android:foregroundServiceType="location" but in Android 11 beta it does not receive locations anymore.

Is this manner new in 11 or just a bug? I did not see anything in the documents.

Comment: have you given the permission ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Comment: @ShaluTD No, but it was not necessary for foreground services, is it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Android 11, a foreground "location" service is no longer enough to get background location updates. We now need to request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, if the foreground service is started in the background (such as a broadcast receiver):

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Even worse, you have to request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION separately from the other location permissions, or it won't work:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/location

Answer (score 1):

Currently the app only get's location updates if a foreground service is running and the activity was in foreground. Then you can put the app into background or turn the screen off and it keeps getting location updates.

If the foreground service is launched after the app was put into background, e.g. by a BroadcastReceiver, then it doesn't get location updates.

As a workaround we would have to request background location permissions.

Seems that this is an open issue for Android 11: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158814176

Comment: What about foreground service with the START_STICKY flag? I mean starting a foreground service from the activity. Has this service still access to location after it is restarted by the system (e.g. due to low memory)?